# Can I change H2 embedded DB dialect to Sybase?

Tags: sybase, h2, mybatis, dbunit

I need to write some test on my project which use Sybase DB. These tests closely related to running some SQL requests. For this purpose we must use myBatis and DBunit approach with h2 embedded DB. But issue is that some Sybase and h2 has a little bit different syntax for same functions.

Example:

```
    Sybase: CONVERT(data_type, expression [, format_style])
    H2: CONVERT(value, data_type)
```

So as you can see if I will write SQL's based on H2 dialect tests will be passed but code in application which will run it on Sybase will fail for sure.

Questions:

1. Is there any way how make H2 DB understand Sybase dialect?
2. Is there any way how to make SQL's to be compatible on different DB's and this is exactly what I need bcos there is a chance that in future we can move to another DB and rewrite all SQL's will be a very bad and time consuming?

Answer (score 0):

1: only if you implement a sql function named CONVERT() that takes the same arguments.

2: SQL dialects quickly get very different once you move beyond the basics like SELECT syntax (and then still...). Built-in functions tend to be vendor-specific. Slso, see answer 1 above,

Answer (score 0):

in the worse case scenario, you may make use of databaseIdProvider and provide a different SQL for each of the different database.

Ensure the following configuration is in place:

```
<databaseIdProvider type="DB_VENDOR">
    <property name="HSQL Database Engine" value="hsql" />
    <property name="Adaptive Server Enterprise" value="sybase"/> 
</databaseIdProvider>
```

then in the mapper.xml, you can do as follows:

to be use by both:

```
<select id="select1" resultType="string" parameterType="int">
    select
    name from common where id=#{value}
</select>
```

to use by hsql only:

```
<select id="select1" resultType="string" parameterType="int" databaseId="hsql">
    ...
</select>
```

to use by sybase only

```
<select id="select1" resultType="string" parameterType="int" databaseId="sybase">
    ...
</select>
```